# Old Chime box popping noise

Tags: doorbell

My wired doorbell started making a "pop" sound every 15 seconds about 10 days ago. The sound is coming from the speaker. I've checked all of the connections and nothing is loose. The noise occurs even when the wiring from the button to the chime is disconnected. The unit is 18 years old. Any help would be appreciated.  I have a new chime box connected.

Comment: I take it this is simply a unit that takes 16-24VAC in and makes chiming noises?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: try running it off batteries and see if that helps.

Comment: My question @jsotola is: why does my chime make popping noises all of a sudden when it is disconnected from the front doorbell that is now connected to a brand new chime box that was installed 16 years ago when I bought the house

Comment: Is it the "wired doorbell", the speaker, or the chime box that's making the popping noise? If it's the old chime box, simply uninstall it and toss it in the bin. The popping noise will disappear next garbage day.